# Bind a Main Class variable to Control Class event in javaFX Eclipse Application

Tags: eclipse, class, javafx, bind

The Control class object is created in Main class. The button event of Control changes the value of Main class variable. I want to show the new value as text of same button. The variable value is changed but not shown in Button. I used bind in Main class to bind it's variable to Control class button event. The Main class is below:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;

public class Main extends Application {

Control controller = new Control();
public static int total_time = 60;
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try 
    {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("/test.fxml"));
        AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
        
        primaryStage.setTitle("TEST Bind Another Class Variable");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
         
  //scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);                       
        primaryStage.show();
        controller = (Control) loader.getController();
        
        controller.btnDemo.textProperty().bind(new 
       SimpleIntegerProperty(total_time).asString());
        
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
 }
 }
```

The Control class is :
package application;

```
 import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
 import javafx.event.Event;
 import javafx.fxml.FXML;
 import javafx.stage.Stage;
 import javafx.scene.Scene;
 import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
 import javafx.scene.text.Text;
 import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
 import javafx.scene.control.Button;
 import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
 import javafx.scene.control.Label;

  public class Control {
  @FXML TextField txtMain;
  @FXML Button btnDemo;
  @FXML
    public void demoBtnHandler(ActionEvent event) 
   {        
    if((Main.total_time+=10) > 60)Main.total_time = 10;
    System.out.print("Button Clicked, Time = ");System.out.println(Main.total_time);
    }
   }
```

The FXML file is:

```
  <?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
  <?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
  <?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
  <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

 <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="- 
 Infinity" prefHeight="630.0" prefWidth="925.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" 
 xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Control">
 <children>
   <Button fx:id="btnDemo" layoutX="412.0" layoutY="339.0" mnemonicParsing="false" 
   onAction="#demoBtnHandler" text="DEMO" />
  <TextField id="tf" fx:id="txtMain" layoutX="412.0" layoutY="298.0" prefHeight="26.0" 
  prefWidth="50.0" />
  <Label layoutX="484.0" layoutY="306.0" text="enter roll no. " />
  </children>
  </AnchorPane>
```

I could not resolve. Please run this code at your end.

Comment: you might want to study a tutorial on properties (and binding) in javafx - your mental model about is is wrong (as shown in the answer): there is no magic that makes a plain int notify a property that takes that int as initial value nor does the property update the initial value :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a very strange thing to do, because the `Application` class is supposed to manage the application lifecycle (it has `start()`, `stop()`, and `init()` methods for this purpose). It's not supposed to be a repository for your application data.

The reason your button text isn't changing is because the text is bound to an `IntegerProperty`, but you don't ever change the `IntegerProperty`. All you change is the `int` value that was originally used to initialize the `IntegerProperty`. To get the text to change you need to change the property.

In `Main`, do:

```
public static IntegerProperty totalTime = new SimpleIntegerProperty(60);
```

and then in the `start()` method:

```
controller.btnDemo.textProperty().bind(totalTime.asString());
```

Then in the controller do

```
@FXML
public void demoBtnHandler(ActionEvent event) {
    Main.totalTime.set(Main.totalTime.get()+10);
    if(Main.totalTime.get() > 60)Main.totalTime.set(10);
    System.out.print("Button Clicked, Time = ");System.out.println(Main.totalTime);
}
```

But again, the design here is all wrong. You should not have public fields, should not be making fields static for no apparent reason, and should not be using the `Application` class to store data. It would probably make more sense to store the value in the controller class, though in a real application you would want to factor the application state into a separate class entirely (a "model" in MVC and related architectures).

Answer (score 0):

I modified the whole code according to MVC as shown below and accessed the Button Events also as suggested by one viewer. The issue got resolved,

```
  import javafx.application.Application;
  import javafx.stage.Stage;
  import javafx.scene.Scene;
  import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


   public class Main {


   public static void main(String[] args) {
    //launch(args);
    Application.launch(Spm.class);
   }
   }
```

In spm class, created objects of all other classes as shown below. All it worked well.

```
 public class Spm extends Application {
 static serialPortClass spm_device = new serialPortClass();

static Control controller = new Control();
static PatientDB patientDataBase = new PatientDB();
static UartCom uartcom = new UartCom();
static NewPatientController patientcontrol = new NewPatientController(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null); 

public Spm() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try 
    {   
      //Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/main.fxml"));
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("Abc.fxml"));
        AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
        
        primaryStage.setTitle("ABC_XYZ");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        //scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);                       
        primaryStage.show();
        controller = (Control) loader.getController();  

        System.out.println("The Loader Path : "+ loader.getLocation().toURI());

      } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    }
```